# Can't see "publish_pages" or "manage_pages" in my Facebook App uses cases dashboard

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I have created my App (which is in development mode) , and linked it to my user profile.

When I request my Page access token

```
curl -i -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/USERID/accounts?access_token=USERTOKEN"
```

I only get :

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

I have read that I need to add business_management, publish_pages, manage_pages permissions to my app but  those permissions do not appear when I'm on the "Use cases" page (in my app's dashboard).

[image]

With the "Authentication and account creation" I only can read user's profile fields.

I want my app to create posts on a page managed by my own facebook profile. My business account is "verified" and I have answers their question regarding "Data handling".

I don't see any kind of "publish on pages" use case. I clicked everywhere. I don't see where I can add those permissions.

Is that normal?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per Facebook Graph API v7.0 Released May 5, 2020

> The manage_pages and publish_pages permissions will be fully
> deprecated in May of 2022.

```
The manage_pages permission has been deprecated and replaced with 4 new permissions:
 - pages_manage_ads
 - pages_manage_metadata
 - pages_read_engagement
 - pages_read_user_content


The publish_pages permission has been deprecated and replaced with 2 new permissions:

 - pages_manage_posts
 - pages_manage_engagement
```

For more details kindly refer the following documentation.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version7.0/

To create a Page post on Facebook Page, go through the following
documentation, if any issues further feel free to ping.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages-api/posts/

Comment: OK I see. But when I go to /me/accounts/ I got the message "The field 'accounts' is only accessible on the User object after the user grants one of the following permissions: 'pages_show_list'."  But in my Use cases dashboard, I don't see where I  can request this permission. In my Facebook login code, when I ask for this permission with  FB.login(function(response) {
  // handle the response
}, {scope: 'pages_show_list'});
            
        }; I got an error

Comment: And of course, the facebook user with the user access token used for the API request has "Administrator" roll for the app.

Comment: What error is it giving?

Comment: "Sorry, something went wrong.
We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can." But I think the problem comes from that app's dashboard I don't see where I can add the permission pages_show_list

Comment: I started. a new question, because the permission I was refering at is deprecated. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77891331/cant-see-how-to-add-pages-show-list-to-my-facebook-app-in-development-mode